# Why is my Kyocera Echo taking 6 minutes to boot?

Tags: boot, bootloader

I have a Kyocera Echo that now takes about 6 minutes to boot. I haven't rooted it or tried to perform any 'hacks' on it. I've had it for a few months now. It's running Android 2.3 if that helps. I am not sure if it is meant to take this long to boot. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup your data and perform a factory reset( `settings` > `privacy` > `factory data reset`). Then restore the data.